# How to get NWEndPoint from device

Tags: ios, swift, networking

I am using NWListener, NWBrowser, and NWConnection for a local peer-to-peer discovery app. Because the vc with both the browser and listener initializes them both, I end up connecting with myself. The only way that I could think of to prevent that is to stop execution with a `return` statement if the `connection.endPoint` is equal to the device's `endPoint` eg.

```
listener?.newConnectionHandler = { (nwConnection) in

    if nwConnection.endpoint == self.deviceEndpoint { return }
}

browser?.browseResultsChangedHandler = { (results, changes) in
    for result in results {

        if result.endpoint == self.deviceEndpoint { return }
    }
}
```

How can I get the device's `NWEndPoint`?

vc:

```
var browser: PeerBrowser?
var listener: PeerListener?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    listener = PeerListener()

    browser = PeerBrowser()
}
```

Listener:

```
class PeerListener {

    var listener: NWListener?

    var deviceEndpoint: NWEndPoint?

    init() {

        self.deviceEndpoint = ???

        let tcpOptions = NWProtocolTCP.Options()
        // ...
        let params = NWParameters(tls: nil, tcp: tcpOptions)
        params.includePeerToPeer = true

        listener = try? NWListener(using: params)
        listener?.service = NWListener.Service(name: "MyName", type: "_myApp._tcp")

        listener?.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in ... }

        listener?.newConnectionHandler = { (nwConnection) in
            
            if nwConnection.endpoint == self.deviceEndpoint { return } // *** STOP EXECUTION HERE ***
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Browser:

```
class PeerBrowser {

    var browser: NWBrowser?

    var deviceEndpoint: NWEndPoint?

    init() {

        self.deviceEndpoint = ???

        let params = NWParameters()
        params.includePeerToPeer = true
        
        browser = NWBrowser(for: .bonjour(type: "_myApp_.tcp", domain: "local"), using: params)

        browser?.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in ... }

        browser?.browseResultsChangedHandler = { (results, changes) in
            for result in results {
                
                if result.endpoint == self.deviceEndpoint { return } // *** STOP EXECUTION HERE ***

                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way i fixed this was to include a unique uid (like the current userId) in the message and when it's received I filter.

Send message:

```
let data = // whatever the data is the currentUID is sent along with it

let message = NWProtocolWebSocket.Metadata(opcode: .text)
let context = NWConnection.ContentContext(identifier: "send", metadata: [message])
connection.send(content: data, contentContext: context, isComplete: true, completion: .contentProcessed({ (error) in
    if let error = error { return }
        
    print("Successfully Sent: \(data.count) bytes")
}))
```

Receive message

```
connection.receive(minimumIncompleteLength: 1, maximumLength: 4200) { [weak self](data, context, isComplete, error) in
    
    if let err = error { return }
    
     if let data = data, !data.isEmpty {
        
         // parse the data and if the uid in the data is equal to the current user's id then return 
     }
}
```